# Google Maps not displaying on navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2, and am displaying a Google Map. It works fine the first time I navigate to it from the root page, but if I navigate to it from another page I have, the map does not display, it's just a blank ionic card.

When the map works, the html looks like:

```
<ion-card id="map" class="e-map" style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;">
<div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
```

But when it doesn't:

```
<ion-card id="map" class="e-map"></ion-card>
```

So It looks like the map is not being loaded onto the DOM I think when I navigate to it?

When I load the map, it finds the `htmlElement` both times (i.e. it's not `undefined`):

```
var htmlElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("map");
```

As far as I can see, the page is being invoked exactly the same way both times. Except when it does not work I use the following to navigate to the page:

```
this.nav.insert(1, EPage, {
```

wen it works I use:

```
this.nav.push(EPage, {
```

My code:

**html**

```
  <ion-card id="map" class="e-map" *ngIf="fromSearch"></ion-card>
```

**ts**

```
let mapOptions = {
  center: bound.getCenter(),
  maxZoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var htmlElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("map");
this.map = new google.maps.Map(htmlElement, mapOptions);
```

Thank you

Comment: I have tried resizing the map after it loads, but no success.

Comment: At what point do you create the map? e.g. in the page constructor or in one of Ionic's page load events?

Comment: Hi Will, I load the map in    `ionViewLoaded(): void {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.loadMap();
      });
    }`